# Optimize loading data into table with clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, etl

I have a datamart on SQL2012 Enterprise that is refreshed completely every month. Loading takes some 8 hours. That's not a problem directly but the team that pushes this data has many more to do so I'd like to keep it short.

Every table has 1 clustered index.
Most tables will have other (probably columnstore) indexes

My idea now is

1. drop all indexes except clustered indexes (they stay)
2. truncate all tables
3. push data into tables sorted by clustered index
4. recreate non-clustered indexes.

Does it actually matter if I load the data already ordered? It would make sense to just create all pages sequentially and never have to split/ reorganize, but I don't see it mentioned anywhere. Any experience? Or is it better to load the table with no indexes even without the clustered index?

Would experiment myself but that would be very hard given the different teams and workload. If anyone has concrete experience that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I cannot give you a definite answer, but in my experience, dropping all indexes (clustered and non-clustered) before loading the (unordered) data, seems to be the fastest for datawarehouse workloads. But if you're not spending any significant amount of time getting the data sorted in the ETL, then you should definitely keep the clustered index.

Comment: I'd be remiss if I didn't throw in a link to [The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd425070), which is not quite the definitive word on this topic, but it's close. In particular, trace flag 610 (which enables minimal logging for clustered index inserts) allows bulk loads on big partitioned tables far, far more efficiently than dropping the clustered index would.

Comment: A full answer to your question depends on what technology you're using for the actual bulk load. For example, `SqlBulkCopy` doesn't support ordering hints, so it doesn't matter if you pre-sort the data before pushing it to SQL Server -- it will have to be sorted at the server end anyway. In general, pushing the data sorted is a good idea, provided you can inform SQL Server that this is the case.

Comment: Hi it gets pushed from an iSeries database through DataStage.

Comment: [This DataStage](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibminfodata)? We have a `datastage` tag, feel free to add it if it's appropriate. It would seem to me that, performance-wise, you would be bound by however DataStage pushes data to the server, right?

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I read the article you pointed, this indeed suggests sorting it should at least be faster on the insert side (because of logging, although it mentions the pages thing too). Sorting rows is not that hard so I'll try that approach first. Thanks!